# Can't get ModelForm to show in template - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have been trying to get this form to show for about 8hours now with no luck. I have read the just about every question on this site and others and those didn't resolve my problem.

models.py

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=('First Name'), max_length=35, null=True,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last Name'), max_length=35,null=True,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def get_quote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            #form.save()
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/testing/thank-you/')
    else:
        form = QuoteForm()
    return render(request, 'request-for-quote.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('', 
    url(r'^testing/request-for-quote/','lsr.views.get_quote',
        name='get_quote'),)
```

request-for-quote.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<button type="submit">{% trans "Request Quote" %}</button></form>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I use shell commands to display the form it shows me the html and renders in the console. just wont display in html template. What am i doing wrong? (EDIT) I forgot to mention that if i change the action to "get_quote" and you click on the button it will redirect to the thank you page above. Just won't show the form fields.

shell commands

```
>>>from lsr.forms import QuoteForm
>>>from lsr.models import Quote
>>>form = QuoteForm()
>>>form.as_p()
```

Help resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Yes I'm new to Django & Python.

UPDATE:
I believe my views.py is not even getting called. The only other 2 defs i have are for the 404 and 500 view so i turned debug to off in my settings and got a bad request instead of my custom 404 pages. So now I'm looking at how to get Django-CMS and Django forms to work together. I'm going to try [this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-hooks) and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Is that the entire "request-for-quote.html" file?

Comment: No the entire file is 
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}   
    {% load i18n %}

    {% block content %}

    <h2>Request a Quote</h2>    
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">{% trans "Request Quote" %}</button>
</form>

{% endblock content %}

Comment: Just for the sake of it and because it's fast, could you try renaming the context variable `form` to sth. else, like `my_form`? I remember that I had to do that once w/ Django CMS but I can't remember if it was because I had another form by the name `form` in it or if it was used up by django cms.

Comment: It probably won't affect anything, but you have `verbose_name=('First Name')` in your model where it should be `verbose_name=_('First Name')` (note the underscore was missing)

Comment: You should also install `django-debug-toolbar` as it will allow you to see what variables are being sent to the template from the view (and therefore be able to see if your template is getting the `form`)

Comment: Here is a wild guess - do you, by any chance have a `templates/request-for-quote.html` and also a `templates/<appname>/request-for-quote.html` ? and you are calling the wrong template in the `render` method ?

Comment: @sthzg i tried that and still no form showing. i also have used the form.as_p and my_form.as_p and didn't work either.

Comment: @timmy that was a typo when transferring it over In the file it is verbose_name=_('First Name'). I'll install the toolbar and see what I can see

Comment: @karthikr, no. the only request-for-quote.html is the templates/request-for-quote

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I installed the toolbar and under requests the only variables i see coming in are the admin ones. and same with views.

Comment: Also, by the way, you don't need `null=True` on `CharField`s. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null

Comment: And you should lose the `or None` from your form instantiation in the view.

Comment: As a debugging step, you could try passing and displaying another variable to see if your context dictionary is successfully being passed.  Like change your view to `return render(request, 'request-for-quote.html', {'form': form, 'got_passed':"I got passed!",})` then change your template to `{% block content %} {{got_passed}} ... {% endblock content %}`

Comment: @Danos2000  The got_passed variable isn't getting passed and neither is the form variable. The form works with the shell commands it's on the views.py that is not working. If i change the action to "get_quote" and press the button it will redirect me to the thank-you page. but if it's blank it just redirects to itself, but either way no variables are getting passed from the views.py

Comment: So at least that pinpoints your problem.  I don't see any obvious issue with your `views.py` posted here. I'd double-check your actual file for typos and make sure to restart my app and try again.  Pay careful attention to your indents, for example.  If, by accident, your `else:` block is indented too far, that would explain the behavior you're seeing.  If you have any tabs in your views.py, convert them all to spaces...mixing whitespace types is one of those common errors for Python newbies.